# Shortest concise readable syntax to iterate over consecutive numbers from given range

Tags: java, loops, iteration, java-stream

In `groovy` I can iterate through numbers using that simple syntax:

```
(1..10).each {
    do_domething it
}
```

What is the shortest syntax to do that in Java? I am now exploring streams and I came up with such an idea:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .forEach(do_domething());
```

It is even longer than the traditional way (below), but seems to be more concise.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    do_domething()
```

I am just curious if there is shorter and readable way of doing it. I don't know everything about Java so I am just asking, probably there is no such thing, but I would like to make sure.

Comment: What's wrong with the traditional way?

Comment: what is your question? not clear to me.

Comment: I can't see where the problem is with the `for (int i ... )` writing *less* characters of code doesn't make it run faster... or whatever

Comment: The question is: is there a shorter syntax to write a loop? well.. you can use a `int i = 10; while(i != 0){ dowathever(); i--;}`

But sincerely I really do not think that it is a better implementation.

Comment: Shorter does not necessarily mean easier to read/or and understand.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not saying that there is something wrong, I am just curious if there is shorter and readable way of doing it. I don't know everything about Java so I am just asking, probably there is no such thing, but I would like to make sure.

Comment: @Braj Shortest readable way of iterating through numbers

Comment: @FredMaggiowski You don't say...

Comment: @Ceelos I am just curious if there is shorter and readable way of doing it. I don't know everything about Java so I am just asking, probably there is no such thing, but I would like to make sure.

Comment: @ctomek, note that you rarely need `forEach()` in normal application. If you want to solve some real problem, it would usually be shorter. For example, `IntStream.range(0, 10).sum()` is shorter than `int s = 0;for(int i=0; i<10; i++) s+=i;`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `IntStream.range` repeatedly in one class, you can reduce verbosity by using a static import:

```
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.range;
```

Then the syntax becomes

```
range(0, 10).forEach(...)
```

Beyond that, there's not much else I can suggest. In my view it *is* a bit ridiculous that we have to write `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` repeatedly, but at least it has the advantage of being instantly recognisable.

Answer (score 2):

There are some major differences between those two that do not make them drop in replacements of each other.

A return from a regular for-loop will return from your method, but for the stream/lambda version it returns from the lambda function.  See below.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 5) {
            return;//returns from the whole method
        }
    }

    IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach((i -> {
        if (i == 5) {
            return; //returns only from the lambda
        }
    }));
```

Another major difference is how the two code blocks interact with variables.  For lambdas to interact with variables that our outside its scope, they need to be final.  So the stream/lambda code below won't compile.

```
    String x = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 5) {
            x = "5";
        }
    }

    IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach((i -> {
        if (i == 5) {
            x = "5"; //wont compile
        }
    }));
```

There might be other differences between the two.  But for me that last one has caused problems that has lead me to continue using the regular for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want concise you can use a helper method.

```
public static void each(int start, int end, IntConsumer consumer) {
    IntStream.range(start, end).forEach(consumer);
}
```

and then you can write

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

each(0, 10, out::println);
```

If "each" is a bit verbose you could use a [connector](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm) character like

```
public static void ⁀(int start, int end, IntConsumer consumer) {
    IntStream.range(start, end).forEach(consumer);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    ⁀(0, 10, out::println);
}
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function to create an array

```
public static int[] range(final int length){
    return IntStream.range(0, length).toArray();
}
```

Then using a foreach loop all you need to write is:

```
for(int i : range(10)) {
    do_domething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the so-called "Facetious Arrow" operator (it looks like an arrow "-->") to write the loop slightly more briefly. [Pro Tip: It's not really an arrow]

```
for (int i=10;i-->0;)doSomething();
```

For example:

```
for (int i=10;i-->0;)System.out.println(i);
```

Prints:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```